# Bundling a message stream

Tags: ros, stream, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking to 'bundle' a stream of ROS messages (on different topics) into a single message that contains bundles (i.e. tuples) of the individual message. Is there a package out there that does something similar?

To give a concrete example, I might have two topics A and B that publish messages at possibly different rates (horizontal space is time):

```
A: a_1,     a_2,      a_3, ... 
B: b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, b_5, b_6, ...
```

and I want a single stream of tupled message bundles:

```
Bundles: (a_1, b_1), (a_2, b_3), (a_3, b_5), ....
```

For example, these could be stereo image pairs or pairs of sensor data measurements.

Before I write a solution, does someone know if such a bundler package exist?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230394/bundling-a-message-stream/) by [Felix Duvallet](https://answers.ros.org/users/22253/felix-duvallet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2016-03-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the message filters: http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters

and especially this one

http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters/ApproximateTime

/// now with better links

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-29**:
And a link to the parent [message/filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) page, which is slightly more generic.